# Can you do a url redirect to refresh a nested frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to refresh a nested iframe with data received via a postmessage. The nested frame whose src that I do not host is inside an html file that I am hosting which is receiving data from another html file that I also host. I am getting an error same-origin policy message when I try to run a function when the postMessage is received. It is either the code that is wrong or it is not possible to do. "portalmap" is the name of the iframe on the html file containing the nested frame. Here is the function that run when the postMessage is received:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    const apnData = event.data;
    var portalUrl = "https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/parceldetail/" + apnData;
    window.open(portalurl, "portalmap");
}
```

Comment: `I want to refresh a nested iframe with data received via a postmessage.` Okay so where is this iframe? It is inside the window you are opening??

Comment: Yes. This function works  when the frame is not nested such as when I have a frame on a page. In this case the frame I am trying to access a frame inside of the frame on my page.